# How to make 'end game' method in java

Tags: java

so i made a game, in which user needs to guess the random number or letter. I want to make it so that when the user writes 'end game' during the game (when he guesses the number), he is being redirected to the menu (using the main(args); method). In fact, String value cannot be writen in int input. So when i write 'end game' during the game cycle, it just crashes. What should i do?

Heres code of my game:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwoGames {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // main menu
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Choose the game\n Type 'letter' or 'number' to choose the game");
        String UserAnswer = "";
        UserAnswer = scan.next();
        if (UserAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("number")) {
            number(args);
        }else if(UserAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("letter")){
            letter(args);
        }
        
    
    

    

        scan.close();
    } 
         public static void letter (String[] args) {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);     
             String playAgain = "";
             String ReTurn = "";
             String Stop = "";
            
             int numberOfTries = 0;
             
            
            do {
                        
            
              System.out.println("Guess the Letter");


              char randomLetter = (char) (Math.random() * 26 + 65); 
              char enteredLetter = 0; 
              
              while(true){
                 
                 enteredLetter = Character.toUpperCase(scan.next().charAt(0)); 
                 numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;
                if(enteredLetter==randomLetter)
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct Guess");
                    System.out.println("The letter is:"+randomLetter);
                    System.out.println("It only took you " + numberOfTries + " tries! Good work!");      
                    break;
                }
                else if(enteredLetter>randomLetter) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
                    System.out.println("The letter entered is too high");
                }
           
                else if(enteredLetter<randomLetter) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
                    System.out.println("The letter entered is too low");
                }  
              

               }
             
               
               
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
                    playAgain = scan.next();
                    
             }   while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye! \n Type 'return' to return to main menu");
            ReTurn = scan.next();
            if (ReTurn.equalsIgnoreCase("return"))
                main(args);
             
             scan.close();
        }
        
         public static void number(String[] args) { //heres the number guessing game
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String playAgain = "";
                String ReTurn = "";
                String Stop = "";//variable to stop game
              
                
                do {
                    
                    int theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                    int numberOfTries = 0;
                  
                   
                  do {
                    int guess = 0;
                    while (guess != theNumber) {
                         System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                        guess = scan.nextInt();
                        
                        numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;
                        if (guess < theNumber)
                            System.out.println(guess + " is too low. Try again.");
                        else if (guess > theNumber)
                            System.out.println(guess + " is too high. Try again.");
                        else {
                            System.out.println(guess + " is correct. You win!");
                            System.out.println("It only took you " + numberOfTries + " tries! Good work!");
                        }
                        
                    }
                    } while (Stop.equalsIgnoreCase("end game"));
                  main(args);// this sends user to main menu
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
                    playAgain = scan.next();
                } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye! \n Type 'return' to return to main menu");
                ReTurn = scan.next();
                if (ReTurn.equalsIgnoreCase("return"))
                    main(args);
                scan.close();
            }
        }
```

I am novice programmer, so yeah, thats might be a dumb question, because im learning. Anyway, any help and explanation would be useful.

Comment: "it just crashes" is not a problem description. What happens? Also, remove all the `scan.close()` calls, you don't want those.

Comment: You can't just write `end game` at random place, that is not valid java syntax.

Comment: your `while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));` does nothing. It is not part of the loop above it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you should input a string, check if it equals to `"End game"` message and if not continue your code.
For example, replace this line:

```
guess = scan.nextInt();
```

In this code:

```
String input = scan.next();
if(input.equals("End game")){
    main(args);
    return;
}
guess = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

That code get a String input called `input`, check if he equals to `"End game"` and if not continue your guess loop.